# How to convert string indexes between different encodings?

Tags: string, unicode, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

I'm looking for an efficient way to convert indexes into a string with one encoding (say UTF-16) to another string using a different encoding (say UTF-8). Converting a string from one encoding to the other is trivial. The question is only about indexes in the strings.

**Use case:**

I have a backend library working exclusively with UTF-8, which does some parsing, among other things. This is to be used from a C# library. I want to return syntax error positions relative to the original String.

Comment: I don't think there's any straight forward way besides going character by character and counting how many bytes it takes in one encoding vs. the other.

Comment: Yes, that's my current idea too, but I hope for some clever different way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this without iterating through the string and counting how many code units each character will convert into.

However, if you're going 'up' (UTF-8→UTF-16→UTF-32), there are some shortcuts you could take (although I'm hesitant to claim they're more efficient without any benchmark tests):

- If the source index is UTF-8, you only need to read the lead byte to tell the range of the code point. For example, if you read `0xF0`, you know that the code point will be between `U+10000` and `U+10FFFF`; therefore, it will be 2 UTF-16 units (or 1 UTF-32 unit), and you can skip the remaining 3 trail units.
- If the target index is UTF-32, you can simply count the number of lead units–everything becomes 1 UTF-32 unit.

Going 'down' (UTF-32→UTF-16→UTF-8) has no such shortcuts, though.